# Can't set a String to whatever I want to

Tags: java, android

This is the whole Java class. The problem is when: answerList.add(position, item); is activated. if I change item to "-" then it works but if I send any other string it doesn't work. That's weird. But I want to be able to add item. What should I do.

Right now the app crashes when that function the add is supposed to happen.

public class SinglePlayerQuickGame extends Activity {

```
databaseTest testDatabase=new databaseTest();
boolean alternativeIsChosen; //är true om ett alternativ har valts
int chosenAlternative;       //om ett alternativ har valts representer
 String alternativeText;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_player_quick_game);
    alternativeIsChosen=false;
    chosenAlternative=-1;
    alternativeText="";

    final ListView AnswerListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chosenAlternatives);
    final ListView alternativeListview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alternatives);


    final ArrayList<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> alternativeList=new ArrayList<String>();


    for(int i=0; i<testDatabase.alternatives.getSize();i++){
        alternativeList.add(testDatabase.alternatives.getNameOnAPosition(i));
    }

    answerList.add("-");
    for(int i=0; i<testDatabase.chosenAlternatives.getSize();i++){
        answerList.add(testDatabase.chosenAlternatives.getNameOnAPosition(i));
        answerList.add("-");

    final StableArrayAdapter answerAdapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answerList);
    AnswerListview.setAdapter(answerAdapter);

    final StableArrayAdapter alternativeAdapter= new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,alternativeList );
    alternativeListview.setAdapter(alternativeAdapter); 

    AnswerListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          final int position, long id) {

          final String item=(String) alternativeListview.getItemAtPosition(0);

        view.animate().setDuration(0).alpha(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
              @SuppressWarnings("null")
            @Override
              public void run() {

                  if(alternativeIsChosen){


                     answerList.add(position, item);
                     answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     alternativeList.remove(chosenAlternative);
                     alternativeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     alternativeIsChosen=false;
                  }



                view.setAlpha(1);
              }
            });
      }



    });

    alternativeListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
              final int position, long id) {


           final String answerItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            view.animate().setDuration(0).alpha(0)
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                    alternativeIsChosen=true;
                    chosenAlternative=position;

                     answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     alternativeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                  }
                });
          }



        });
  }

public final String getAlternativeText(){
    return alternativeText;
}

  private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }

  }
```

}

The error messages:

```
06-10 10:43:36.009: D/AndroidRuntime(618): Shutting down VM
06-10 10:43:36.009: W/dalvikvm(618): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.example.rankingquiz2.SinglePlayerQuickGame$StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(SinglePlayerQuickGame.java:198)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2292)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1600)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1638)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1422)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 10:43:36.269: D/dalvikvm(618): GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 4% free 6282K/6535K, paused 74ms+9ms, total 200ms
06-10 10:43:36.279: D/dalvikvm(618): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 49ms
```

Comment: Yes, but if I change the string s to something else it doesn't.

Comment: That's *probably* because your items are Strings. You can't just cast to any object you want.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't nearly enough information to help you diagnose the problem. It's like saying to the doctor "I'm not well" but not letting him examine you. In what *way* does it not work? And what *exactly* does the not-working code look like?

Comment: If s is final String s=(String) alternativeListview.getItemAtPosition(position); it doesn't work. Or if I set s equal to variable which is a string it doesn't work either. By not working I mean that the app crashes when this onItemClick() function is reached.

Comment: What is the type of object you add to alternativeList?

Comment: Are you sure that the return value of `getItemAtPosition(position)` can be casted to `String`?

Comment: Hi namero999! Well since final String s = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); works that should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi TactMayers! alternativesList is a: final ArrayList<String>

Comment: Hey @aksh1t - your "reformatting" of the code has rendered it incorrect / uncompilable.  Please be more careful.

Comment: Filip - I tried long and hard to understand your explanation of what it happening, but it is just too unclear.  I'm afraid that unless you can explain clearly and precisely how and where the app is crashing (what exception, what line) this Question is unanswerable.

Comment: Now the whole code is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change it because its declared final a reference variable declared final and assigned to an object that reference variable can't be assigned to another object. So variable s can't reference anything else but what it already holds.

Comment: How do I set a list element equal to a global variable (which is a String)?

Comment: We don't have global variable in java, do you mean static variables?

Comment: No just an ordinary variable

Comment: Set a list element to a particular variable which is a string: list.set(index,string);//index-which element int the list to be equal to the string variable

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do.It doesn't work when I use a string variable. When I tried to write the string directly (just for trying) the string "-" worked properly. But when I wrote strings such as "m", "hello" or "/" it didn't work. Do you have any idea what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: What exceptions/errors does it show when you put other strings??

Comment: " java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 10:43:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.example.rankingquiz2.SinglePlayerQuickGame$StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(SinglePlayerQuickGame.java:198)" this is probably where the problem is. Check that line out

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I removed that function it works. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to click that the answer was useful. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the problem actually is.

However, looking at the code it is *extremely unlikely* that is is a result of "setting the string equal to a variable".

There is something else going on here ... and you have not provided enough information to allow us to figure it out.  The first thing you need to provide is the stacktrace for the exception that is causing the crash.